# Problem embedding pdf files in html

Tags: html, pdf

My website currently embeds pdf files. although resently, after a update or new gpo push, when i view the website in IE 9 or IE 8 the pdfs will launch in adobe reader independently outside of the website verses within the webpage. Embedding works fine when i launch the site within firefox. the page loads currently with IE 7.

Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot this issue would be appreciate it.

Comment: What do you mean by "independently from the website"?

Comment: the pdfs will just launch and dispaly withihn adobe reader instead of displaying within the webpage.

Answer (score 1):

By embedding what exactly do you mean?  Within an iFrame or simply within the browser window?  Does the url end with .pdf?

I believe your problem is linked with the HTTP headers being passed with the PDF - this usually allows you to request what the browser does with the file (Prompt for download, display in window etc).

You need to look at the Content-Disposition header - [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/260519) should put you in the correct direction.